# How to Keep Focus of File-Browser when Previewing Thumbnails in Sushi?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, nautilus, previews, gnome-sushi

A report done [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656951) already 2011 in bugzilla.gnome.org but no proposals for improvement. It is possible that this is not a `gnome-sushi` issue but dependent on the packages on the test environment

- How can you monitor execution times started by <kbd>space</kbd>?
- Why does the focus change after <kbd>space</kbd> in the file-manager?

Test environment

- `sudo apt-get gnome-sushi unoconv`. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> on any `.ppt` file.
  Output: slow visualization of the first page as a thumbnail.
  Expected output: rapid visualization of the thumbnail.

Current process is slow (5-11 seconds for generation)

1. <kbd>Space</kbd> on file name for slow visualisation of the first page of the document.
2. <kbd>Space</kbd> again to stop visualization.
3. <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> key to see the next document.
4. Repeat (1-2) again.

Faster approach proposal

1. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> - slow visualization of the first page of the document starts.
2. Press the <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> key which I would like to moves the document in the file-browser.
3. Repeat (2) to view files fast.
4. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> to stop previews.

Can the proposal be technically possible in Ubuntu 16.04? Here to maintain the focus in the file-manager.

Comment: Is that really the right thing to ask on this plattform? Isn't that more like a question to devs/bug report?

Comment: @Ziazis Yes. It is not a bug according to some developers. It is a feature. I would like to understand why it is a feature. I need to monitor those processes better to understand it better. It is only Ubuntu related.